# Regex not working correctly with python

Tags: python, regex

I have this code

```
site = hxs.select("//h1[@class='state']")
mydata = site.select("string()").extract()
cleaned_mydata = re.sub(ur'(\s)\s+', ur'\1', mydata[0], flags=re.MULTILINE + re.UNICODE)

        log.msg(str(mydata),level=log.ERROR)
        log.msg(str(cleaned_mydata),level=log.ERROR)
```

The first output is

> ERROR: [u'\r\n        212\r\n         jobs containing php in xxxx
>   \r\n            ']

other output is

> jobs containing php in xxxxxx

regex is also stripping the `212` numeric with it. how can i fix that

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: I am trying to delete the more than one space and end lines. i copied this from internet , i don't know what it does exactly

Comment: As a test, why not replace with something visible, instead of: ur'\1', use: 'XYZ'. Before you run the regex, why not remove the \r\n? Also, when using flags= they should be OR'd together, not ADDED (i.e use | not +)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this regex leaves the first whitespace it finds and strips only the subsequent ones.

This means that

```
u'\r\n 212\r\n jobs containing php in xxxx \r\n '
```

becomes

```
u'\r212\rjobs containing php in xxxx '
```

When you print this, the `212` will be printed, then a carriage return will return the cursor to the first column, so that the following `jobs...` will overwrite the `212`.

This raises two questions:

- You appear to be reading a text file in binary mode (otherwise the `\r\n` would have been normalized into `\n`s) - why?
- Do you really want the regex to work this way?

**Edit:**

So, according to your comment, you want to

- strip leading and trailing whitespace completely
- condense multiple consecutive whitespace characters into a single space (ASCII 32).

Then use

```
cleaned_mydata = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', mydata[0].strip())
```

Comment: I am scrapping the website with scrapy and using there. i don't know why it was appearing like that. i only want to remove the blamk spaces and \r\n

Comment: @user32: Please be more specific. What *exactly* do you want to remove? I don't think you want your result to be `212jobscontainingphpinxxxx`.

Comment: i want the result to be `212 jobs containing php in xxx`